# Can't disable server side HtmlAnchor from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've tried:

```
btnSubmitPhaseBackward.Disabled = true;
btnSubmitPhaseBackward.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
btnSubmitPhaseBackward.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

Here's the markup:

```
<a id="btnSubmitPhaseBackward" runat="server" onclick="saveEvent('backward');this.blur();return false;" href="javascript:void(0);" ><span id="btnSubmitPhaseBackwardValue" runat="server">Submit</span></a>
```

Neither work and doing it on the client side is not an option. It has to be disabled from the server side, but it needs to be able to be re-enabled from javascript if needed.

Comment: Can u please show the markup?

Comment: @NicholasV If Its not set as runat=server you can't even access this from code behind!

Comment: @Fals , yep my mistake. Removed

Comment: markup added to question

Comment: Where are you setting the attribute? Page_Load? Event? You should set any attribute from code behind in OnPreRender Method. Theres something else messing your change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have ***Click event*** attached to the anchor.

So, only way to disable from server side is to remove click event.

```
btnSubmitPhaseBackward.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
```

If you want to reenable it at client side, you just need to reattach the Click event again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
btnSubmitPhaseBackward.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

UPDATE:

So it turns out that the `disabled` attribute does not really do what you think it should, to truly disable an `HtmlAnchor` you have to remove the `href` attribute, like this:

```
btnSubmitPhaseBackward.Attributes.Remove("href");
```

To re-enable the `HtmlAnchor` you would need to add the `href` attribute back, like this:

```
btnSubmitPhaseBackward.Attributes.Add("href", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: Dont forget to mention that Its recomended to do this at the OnPreRender event. Maybe something else a long the way is messing up his change. And disabled don't necessary need a value, just need the attribute placed into the markup.